# Loop over Error in the InputBox for sheet creation or copied sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code to copy and name worksheets, this code warns me when I have a worksheet with the same name and request another name, but I can make it request this only once before copying a worksheet, I would like it I got the name wrong again he would ask until the name was accepted before copying the worksheet. But I'm not able to do the loop, and whenever he asks the second time, he already copies the worksheet even without having typed the name yet.

```
Sub CopySheet()


    Dim i As Integer, x As Integer
    Dim shtname As String
    
    shtname = InputBox("Worksheet Name?", "Name?")
    If StrPtr(shtname) = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
    On Error GoTo errhandler
    End If
errhandler:
    shtname = InputBox("Name taken!", "Name?")
    If StrPtr(shtname) = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
    On Error GoTo errhandler
    End If
    
    Sheets("MODELO").Copy Before:=Sheets("CC")
    ActiveSheet.Name = shtname

    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**

There are a couple of things to be addressed aside from checking if the sheet exists, like length of the name given and if special characters are written as well (some may be accepted but some others not). I appended those, you were right on getting labels, just a quick change on how to do it

**Demo Solution**
[image]

**Code**

```
Sub CopySheet()
Const SpecialCharacters As String = " ||!||@||#||$||%||^||&||*||,||(||)||{||[||]||}||?||¿||¡||.||;||:||/||\||=||-||_||'||<||>||+||»||ï|||"
Dim Varchar As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, x As Integer
    Dim shtname As String
    Dim WSDummy As Worksheet
    Dim TxtError As String
Loop01ValidName:
    TxtError = ""
    shtname = InputBox("Worksheet Name?", "Name?")
    If StrPtr(shtname) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    For Each Varchar In Split(SpecialCharacters, "||"): If InStr(shtname, Varchar) > 0 Then TxtError = IIf(TxtError = "", "No special characters allowed!", TxtError & Chr(10) & "No special characters allowed!"): Exit For
    Next Varchar
    If Len(shtname) > 31 Then TxtError = IIf(TxtError = "", "No special characters allowed!", TxtError & Chr(10) & "Maximum characters for sheet are 31!")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WSDummy = Sheets(shtname)
    If Not (WSDummy Is Nothing) Then TxtError = IIf(TxtError = "", "Name taken!", TxtError & Chr(10) & "Maximum characters for sheet are 31!")
    If TxtError <> "" Then MsgBox "Error(s)" & TxtError: GoTo Loop01ValidName
    'Be aware if sheets are very hidden will result in error, just be aware of that
    'Sheets("MODELO").Visible= False:Sheets("CC").Visible= False
    Sheets("MODELO").Copy Before:=Sheets("CC"): ActiveSheet.Name = shtname
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, one point: i wanna allow space on the sheet name, so i removed as special char

Comment: I'm trying to make it more compact to suit my needs, so I tried removing special character and length checks, just keeping the checks if the name already exists and if I hit cancel, but I'm not getting it, do you have any tips?

Comment: You'd need to delete the code that does it (for each Var char line until the line before on error resume next), but those checks needs to exist, if they happen you'll have an exception thrown by VBA lying around being unhandled: why are you trying to make it more compact instead of functional?

Comment: You have a point, I'm going to remove the check only for the special characters, because I sometimes use them, removing more lines of code would be stupid since I'm using this code in several workbooks. Thank you very much for your attention and work on that code!

Comment: Edit the string SpecialCharacters, I made it for general purposes, so not all of them apply to sheets, but some do as for example a sheet cannot have a name with the character "/", but there are [some others](https://www.excelcodex.com/2012/06/worksheets-naming-conventions/#:~:text=A%20worksheet%20name%20cannot%20exceed,underscores%20(_)%20and%20periods%20(.)), you may see it if you try to rename the sheet and type one of those, it just won't happen. The input box would allow them, but you'll end up with an exception when you try to create it if they use it.